# Text in buttons not appearing at iphones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, button, text

I have some problems with appearing text in buttons of answers after the first screen when you clicked to 'play' on iPhones.  For example. it works everywhere, but not on iPhones. Here is the demo version - https://xahtc.github.io/test-app and here you can find my project on react - https://github.com/xahtc/test-app. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: @ShamarYarde can you provide me a screen please, because I checked a lot of devices and there are no problems with adaptive

Comment: Sorry about the deleted comment.  I don't know how to provide a screenshot on Stack Overflow.  Only location I can think of is the answer section, but that's only for answers.  It works on Android though using the Samsung Internet browser.

Comment: @ShamarYarde yes, it works on Macbooks too, tested it, but on IPhones it is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that on Safari IOS at least (I tested on an iPad IOS 14) the pseudo elements on Game_answer__2Ffxs are rendering in front of the text in the answer boxes, despite having z-index: -1.

I hesitate to talk about z-index and stacking contexts and transforms and all that stuff because I've got it wrong in the past, but the important thing for this question is that on IOS the text is being overwritten and the negative z-index isn't having the desired effect.

One immediate thing to try is to put the `background-color: #fff` to for example something semi transparent (I used `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`) so you can see for yourself what those pseudo elements are covering.

You'll see the text is there, but also you'll see the central line that no doubt these pseudo element were meant to cover. There will have to be another way of getting rid of that I guess - or drop it for now in the interests of the user seeing the answers and replace the #fff with transparent.